# Обработка нажатий на UIButton

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uibutton

Здрав­ствуй­те. 
В iPhone-​при­ло­же­нии име­ет­ся кноп­ка, по на­жа­тию на ко­то­рую ме­ня­ет­ся те­ку­щая ком­по­зи­ция в пле­е­ре:

```
-(void)nextTrack{
    [player stop];
    int new_index = [listOfItems indexPathForSelectedRow].row +1;
    [self changeTrackForNumber:new_index];
    [listOfItems selectRowAtIndexPath:
                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:new_index
                       inSection:0]
                 animated:YES
                 scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle]; 
}
```

Т.е. про­сто ме­ня­ет­ся те­ку­щая ячей­ка в UITableView (*listOfItems*) и трек.
Все за­ме­ча­тель­но ра­бо­та­ет, но ес­ли я бу­ду на­жи­мать на эту кноп­ку с пе­ре­о­дич­но­стью бо­лее 3 раз в се­кун­ду (ну где-​то так), пле­ер как-​то некор­рект­но на нее ре­а­ги­ру­ет — не успе­ва­ет оста­но­вить те­ку­щее вос­про­из­ве­де­ние и по­лу­ча­ет­ся, что 2-​ой трек на­чи­на­ет иг­рать «по­верх» пер­во­го. По­вли­ять на ско­рость пе­ре­клю­че­ния до­ро­жек я, по­жа­луй, ма­ло чем мо­гу (пле­ер не мной пи­сан).

Ло­гич­ным ре­ше­ни­ем про­бле­мы вро­де бы яв­ля­ет­ся за­клю­че­ние ко­да в блок **@synchronized**:

```
@synchronized (self) {
    //мой код
}
```

Т.е. по­ка сме­ня­еть­ся трек, все на­жа­тия на кноп­ку, по су­ти, бу­дут иг­но­ри­ро­вать­ся.
Про­бле­ма в том, что ре­зуль­тат не ме­ня­ет­ся — код вы­пол­ня­ет­ся при всех на­жа­ти­ях.
Тот же са­мый ре­зуль­тат да­ет да­же ба­наль­ное от­клю­че­ние кноп­ки в на­ча­ле ме­то­да и вклю­че­ние ее в кон­це (что дей­стви­тель­но стран­но).  
Есть ли еще ка­кие-​ни­будь спо­со­бы огра­ни­че­ния вы­пол­не­ния ко­да? В иде­а­ле, ко­неч­но, хо­те­лось бы иметь огра­ни­че­ние «раз в се­кун­ду». Спа­си­бо!

Answer (score 1):

Ну, со слипом ведь работает и работает именно так, как Вы написали, а не так, как Вы хотите.

Как вариант завести булевую переменную и таймер (не знаю, как делаются таймеры на Objective-C, может быть позже отпишу более полно).

```
@interface ...
    BOOL nextTrackAllowed;// дальше инициализируем его YES
@end
@implementation ...
-(void)nextTrack{
    if(nextTrackAllowed){
        [player stop];
        int new_index = [listOfItems indexPathForSelectedRow].row +1;
        [self changeTrackForNumber:new_index];
        [listOfItems selectRowAtIndexPath:
                     [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:new_index
                           inSection:0]
                     animated:YES
                     scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        nextTrackAllowed = NO;
        // start timer, по истечении секунды в котором 
        // переменная nextTrackAllowed принимает значение YES

    }else{
        return;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Вот со слипом там все-таки не пашет, нет. Несколько поторопился с выводами просто.
Ну раз уж я дошел да потоков, то все остальные варианты я перепробовал :) И индикаторы занятости и даже отключение самой кнопки. Методы все равно выполняются.